# Is there any way to make the Alt-Tab window changer pop up quicker in Gnome-Shell?

Tags: gnome

I like the behavior of Gnome-Shell's Alt-Tab window changer, but there is a slight delay when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which bothers me. Is there any way to make it pop up immediately, or at least, decrease the delay?

Comment: I think the slight delay is there by design, so if one wants to quickly switch back and forth between two windows via Alt+Tab, for example, then it doesn't have to waste time showing the switcher for a fraction of a second. Just thought I'd point out this is probably not a performance issue on the switcher's part, but an intended feature.

Comment: It can be a performance issue. My setup at this moment is lagging for a full half-second before showing the popup and also before hiding the popup. Now I will restart gnome-shell using ALT+F2 "r". Now, it's back to being snappy again. All I did was restart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can change that in the .js file of the alt-tab.

In

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/altTab.js
```

Almost at the beginning of the file, is this line

```
const POPUP_DELAY_TIMEOUT = 150; // milliseconds
```

Change it, save and restart the gnome-shell (Alt+F2 type 'r', or logout and login again).

Comment: Perfect answer. It's elegant and it works.

Comment: Does this persist across (Gnome Shell) updates? However I just checked and in Ubuntu 17.10 there is no `js` folder inside `/usr/share/gnome-shell`

Answer (score 5):

Since gnome 3.12, the Javascript UI files are embedded inside `libgnome-shell.so`. See [this post](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/24/keeping-gnome-shell-approachable/).

Answer (score 2):

As of 13.10, this setting is now located in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/switcherPopup.js`.